# Load websites in offline mode

Tags: android, android-webview, android-internet

I want to load websites from cache when internet is not connected. Here's how I setup the webview in onCreate:

```
    browse.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browse.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    browse.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browse.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    browse.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    browse.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    browse.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    browse.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    browse.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    browse.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 100);
    browse.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
        browse.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    else
        browse.getSettings().setCacheMode(
                WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

    browse.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            t.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            t.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
        }
    });

    try {
        browse.loadUrl(address);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here's the [tutorial](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/saving-the-android-webview-cache-on-the-sd-card/) I'm following and I'm trying to load the previously visited webpages even if the browser is restarted. Doesn't work! Please help me.

P.S: I have searched all the related codes on SO, none of them works.

Comment: 08-16 15:03:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(2827): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10056 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
 <- that is the cause!

Answer (score 5):

Declare the following permission in your manifest file:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

Comment: This time the app didnt crash but this method doesnt fulfill its purpose, pages are not loaded in offline mode.

Comment: There isnt anything strange in the logcat. It shows that data is received when internet is connected and shows nothing when its not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the call to [`WebSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCacheEnabled%28boolean%29) :)

Also, I think it's probably better to check the connectivity and call `setCacheMode()` before you call `loadUrl()` instead of from within your `onPageStarted()` method (seems like it would be too late).

Lastly, I am not sure whether your override of `getCacheDir()` is necessary, since I believe you are simply calling the default implementation anyway in your override.

**UPDATE:**

After looking at the updated code in the question, I can confirm that I have similar code that worked fine. The only notable difference is I have the following code when checking for connectivity:

```
    final NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    } else {
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }
```

compared to your version:

```
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
        browse.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    else
        browse.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

I tested by running in the emulator and toggling airplane mode on and off.

I did however read the tutorial that you linked more closely (and I understand now why you override `getCacheDir()` in your original code) and am wondering if maybe you are still calling `WebView.clearCache(true)` in the `onDestroy()` of your Activity. If you still have that part from the tutorial unmodified, it will definitely cause the cache appear not to be working :)

Comment: Did it worked? I see you removed a comment saying it still doesn't work.

Comment: No it didnt, I removed the comment realizing that asking someone to fix your source code is inappropriate for this site, isnt it?

Comment: ah, I thought you removed it because it worked out somehow :) Well, do you mind updating the code in your question with the changes that I suggested and still does not work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried nanoHttpd webserver, it is simple solution to get access webpages in sdcard or local memory.. all you want to do is give path to page as ,http://localhost:8081/[your cache directry path to offline webpage] in webview

https://gist.github.com/1893396

I tried this on pages in sdcard and phone memory, hope this will work for you